# difference between {foo()} and {foo}

Tags: jsx

I came across a JSX expression when user clicks on a button, a function must execute.
I want to know difference between referencing a function and calling a function using '()'

E.g.  when to use which?

1)

```
       <button onClick={foo}>Something here</button>
```

2)

```
       <button onClick={foo()}>Something here</button>
```

and the function foo

```
       const foo = () => {
          console.log('something here');            
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
<button onClick={foo()}>Something here</button>
```

will result in calling function foo every time when component renders.

Using

```
<button onClick={foo}>Something here</button>
```

will call it only when button is clicked.